# how to intercept spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client's endpoint?

Tags: spring-oauth2, oauth2client, spring-authorization-server, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I run this [spring-authorization-server samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples) to complete oidc authorization process.
Now I want to intercept `http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc` and get the `code` and `state`.Next, I want to complete the remaining process.

What should I do？

Comment: Intercept in what way?  What are the players here?

Comment: Exchange code and state for accesstoken

Comment: and then use accesstoken to get userinfo.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  If it is your code sending the authorization request, then you'd be getting the response and you wouldn't need to intercept this.  Are you hooping to intercept packets destined for a different application?

Comment: I want to interrupt the original automated processing and implement it myself step by step.